# How to isolate the AM2301 sensor with a small footprint and low-cost isolator (digital or opto)?

Tags: opto-isolator, safety, bidirectional

Looking for a solution for isolating the AM2301 sensor with either digital or opto-isolator. I have space and cost constraints. Thank you .

AM2301 is accessed via a single bus / single line interface for bi-directional communication (SDA) - https://www.micros.com.pl/mediaserver/UPAM2301A_0001.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single-wire protocol AM2301 works like I²C (digital, bidirectional, open-drain). The smallest pulse width is about 25 µs, which corresponds to 40 kbps or 20 kHz.

If you want to prioritize small space, use one channel of an I²C isolator.

If you want to prioritize low cost, you can build a circuit using two optoisolators (this is sometimes used for I²C, with two channels):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOFwHc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 and R3 limit the currents through the optocouplers' LEDs. R1,R2 and R3,R4 act in parallel. D1 and D2 should be Schottky diodes.

20 kHz is probably more than a cheap phototransistor optocoupler (e.g., xx817) can manage; you probably need to use some digital optocoupler like the H11L1.

Comment: The schematic is looking good and I understand the principles. Assuming I go with H11L1, and VCC1 and VCC2 is 3.3V, what would be the recommended R values. Do R1 and R4 also act as pull-ups for the SDA line?

Comment: All resistors act as pull-ups, R2 and R3 through the LEDs. The total pull-up current for I²C should not be larger than 3 mA; the H11L1 wants 1.2 mA.